# 12.10 blue screen, no panels

Tags: 12.10, gnome

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10. The desktop is stuck on a blue screen, the panel bars at the top and bottom don't show up. My 2 screens are set to low resolution and mirror. I can open a terminal with C-M t.

Here's my 
.xsession-erros : http://pastebin.com/USxbzhSL

A good deal of the errors are like :

```
(gnome-settings-daemon:579): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:33:52: Unrecognised image file format
```

Here's what I've tried :

reinstall l`ibgdk-pixbuf2`

`gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache` give me a Seg. fault (http://pastebin.com/yBLssi0r)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

When I go to All Settings/Displays and try to change the resolution of a screen, I get

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XRANDR_2' on object at path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/XRANDR
```

However, I can change the display settings using `arandr`.

I created a new user and the problems persist.

Should I try to update to Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help. Try installing gnome-shell

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Then on login page, select option ubuntu classic (no effects)

Comment: I am not able to select the type of session on the login page. The session button is gone. Is there a command line way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The OP posted this solution in the question.

> Updating to 13.04 fixed the problems (sudo do-release-upgrade -d).
>   Everything is running smoothly now.